# JqGrid with JSON empty Grid

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I read lots of previous questions but I can't solve. I really appreciate help.
I was working with jqGrid with xml, it works great, now I need to use JSON but the grid is allways empty. I'm working with WAMP.

**The server side answers this:**

```
{
    "page":"1",
    "total":"1",
    "records":"2",
    "rows":[
        {"id":"campo1","cell":["campo1","campo3"]},
        {"id":"campo11","cell":["campo11","campo33"]}
        ]
}
```

**The first HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>jqGrid Ejemplo 1: Cargar datos de una tabla MySql </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/flick/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jqgrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-es.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#tblclientes").jqGrid({
    url:'clientes2.php',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames:['ID','NOMBRE'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'idCliente', index:'idCliente', width:50 },
        {name:'nombre', index:'nombre', width:160 }
    ],
    pager: '#paginacion',
    rowNum:10,

    sortname: 'idCliente',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    viewrecords: true
    });              
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="tblclientes"></table>
    <div id="paginacion"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**The server side**

```
<?php
    $page = $_POST['page']; 
    $limit = $_POST['rows'];
    $sidx = $_POST['sidx']; 
    $sord = $_POST['sord']; 

    if(!$sidx) $sidx =1;
    $conexion = new mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","","deyertdb");
    $result = $conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM code2");

    $fila = $result->fetch_array();
    $count = $fila['count'];

    if( $count >0 ) $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit);else $total_pages = 0;
    if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;

    $start = $limit*$page - $limit;

    $consulta = "SELECT StockCode as idCliente, Mfr as nombre FROM code2 ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit;";
    $result = $conexion->query($consulta);

    $respuesta->page = $page;
    $respuesta->total = "$total_pages";
    $respuesta->records = $count;
    $i=0;
    while( $fila = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $respuesta->rows[$i]['id']=$fila["idCliente"];
        $respuesta->rows[$i]['cell']=array($fila["idCliente"],$fila["nombre"]);
                $i++;
    }
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
?>
```

Comment: it's better if you copy the exact code of HTML page. Do you really use `< meta` and not `< meta`? Do you really use `http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"` and not `"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"`? Why you included `...` in may places of your code? Do you really use `jsonreader});` in your code?

Comment: Dear Oleg, I updated the exact code, thanks for your observations.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem which you described. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user3078388.htm) uses practically your code (with minimal modifications) and uses JSON data which I saved in a file. All works without any problems. I am not PHP developer, but probable you should add the line

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

before `echo json_encode($respuesta);`

Comment: Dear Oleg I really thanks your help. I tried with "The demo", this open my mind and more ideas, well finally I found and answer here in stackoverflow.com, it could be funny, but just one PHP line solve everything. Only put      $response = new stdClass();      before 
    $response->page = $page;     Thanks.

Comment: @user3078388: You are welcome! I'm glad if I could help you, but as I wrote I'm not PHP developer, so could only guess in the reason of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dear Oleg I really thanks your help. I worked with your demo loading the JSON string in the file as in "The demo" you give me, this open my mind for more ideas, well finally I found and answer here in stackoverflow.com from Mariousz.
It could be funny, but just one PHP line solve everything. Only put

```
$response = new stdClass();
```

before

```
$response->page = $page;
```

Thanks Oleg and Mariusz

The detailed solution in the last part of
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259435/jqgrid-with-json-data-renders-table-as-empty)